# Can you communicate to a native mobile app from mobile web browser?

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, communication

I want to find a way to run native mobile app, from a web app on a browser, and communicate the result back to it.

For example, how does Facebook user authentication work on a mobile device? You go to login with Facebook on a website. If on mobile, it opens the native Facebook app to do the authentication, and redirects the user back to the mobile web browser to open some page, post-authentication.  Somehow, web browser and native application are able to communicate? Is there also any security risk to this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is as follows:

- Use a custom url to launch the app from the website (see link below)
- Pass whatever parameters you need to the app (for example a return web site URL in the case of a login authentication type app)
- Once the app launches and does it thing, have the app launch a browser using the return address URL you passed as a parameter to the app.

A good, well maintained, link to using custom URL's and passing partakers to the App:

- http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html